# Laravel Eloquent Join Querying can't access all variables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have two models defined (Laravel application): `AdviceProtocol` and `Question` which you the tables `advice_protocols` and `questions`. The models have been linked together by:

```
public function userGoal() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Question', 'id', 'user_goal_id');
    }
```

I would like to get the following variabels from my query: the advice protocol name, the advice protocol category and questions name. The two tables are linked through a set of `ids`. The query which I have now is:

```
public function data(){
        $advicePreparationsQuery = AdviceProtocol::select(['advice_protocols.name', 'advice_protocols.category', 'questions.id'])
        ->join('questions', 'advice_protocols.user_goal_id', '=', 'questions.id')
        ->get();
```

The `questions.id` can be retrieved, but when I change the variable to `questions.name`: nothing is retrieved. My output doesn't give an error, but no values are returned. Could someone please help me to get the value of `questions.name`?

Comment: Did you fill the `fillables` array? May you show your models to us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`name` is ambiguous in your query because you're also selecting `advice_protocols.name`. You need to give one of them an alias so it knows which column is which when you're trying to access `$advicePreparationsQuery->name`

```
$advicePreparationsQuery = AdviceProtocol::select(['advice_protocols.name', 'advice_protocols.category', 'questions.name AS question_name'])
    ->join('questions', 'advice_protocols.user_goal_id', '=', 'questions.id')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I also understand now what I was doing wrong. You're awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$advicePreparationsQuery = AdviceProtocol::select(['advice_protocols.user_goal_id', 'advice_protocols.name', 'advice_protocols.category', 'questions.id', 'questions.name'])
        ->join('questions', 'advice_protocols.user_goal_id', '=', 'questions.id')
        ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are not selecting questions.name...

Try:

```
$advicePreparationsQuery = AdviceProtocol::select([
    'advice_protocols.name', 'advice_protocols.category', 'questions.name'
  ])
  ->join('questions', 'advice_protocols.user_goal_id', '=', 'questions.id')
  ->get();
```